# Web Load testing a website

Tags: apache-2.2, website, load-testing

I have spent time trying to optimize my website but have never got a chance to test maximum users it can take. Have been doing some reading and found out the best scenario would be to use cloud web load testing. The only catch is that its ridicously expensive. Is there any service that can be used to test this that is free and can simulate real browser users.

Answer (score 1):

There are benchmarking tools for Apache2 available, take a look over [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html)

It shows you how you can try to emulate an amount of requests. There are some requirements to make it as reliable as possible, but I guess it should do the trick. There is also a site http://loadimpact.com but I do not know it's reliability.

Comment: i like loadimpact, but has a limit of i think 100 simulated users

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [ZebraTester](http://www.zebratester.com/) and record the script for this test. The trial version allows you to have up to 20 Virtual Users and these can run multiple loops depending on the length of your test. The same tool can record the script as well as run the load test from your local machine.